# What is the best primary key data type for big id?

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I need to store primary key of length 21 (google or facebook uid) which has much more size than int (2147483647 as a maximum value) and BIGINT (9223372036854775807 as a maximum value),

I also read about varchar and realized that it's of low performance and AUTO_INCREMENT issues.

What is the best primary key for such a case?

Comment: Why not create your own id (INT AUTO_INCREMENT if that suffices) and keep a second column for another key with a VARCHAR of enough length?

Comment: That's a good solution, but how can i need to deal with this id as the main id for queries, is there any way for that?

Comment: Just in the very same way you would use any other search key (there is no real difference). Something like `SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE google_id = :value`. All the FKs and other queries can still use the normal numeric id or whatever other search criteria needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `numeric(21, 0)`?  That seems to exactly describe what you are looking for.

I wouldn't say that "varchar has low performance".  What is more accurate is that shorter keys are better and fixed length keys are better.  Hence, strings are not optimal as keys for indexes.  However, they are still very reasonable when needed.

Comment: If using a string for a PK, would you suggest using `CHAR` over `VARCHAR` so that they're always a fixed length?

Comment: Just to observe that the question is tagged MySQL

Comment: @fubar . . . That would require testing to know if the *index* code was sensitive to the type of string used in the key.

Comment: numeric is for Oracle DB, i'm asking for MySQL.

Comment: @Emarco . . . Excuse me?  `numeric`/`decimal` is a *standard* SQL type available in pretty much all databases:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's right it's name is decimal, thanks bro it worked.

Comment: @Emarco . . . `decimal` and `numeric` are synonyms -- in the standard and in every database I know of.